# Vais versus Aille

Tags: choix-de-mot

If you have the following sentence:

> Je **vais** à l'école.

What is the difference between that and:

> J'**aille** à l'école.

Answer (score 5):

- The first difference is the mood (i.e. *mode*) used (indicative vs subjunctive).
- The second difference is that the second sentence is ungrammatical (usually, the subjunctive is introduced by *que*) or at least meaningless.

A way to use the subjunctive with *aller* might be:

> *Mes parents voulaient **que j'aille à l'école** pour apprendre mes conjugaisons.*

Comment: Could you explain your first point more (mood)?

Comment: Does [that page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) help?

Comment: Yes, but I can't accept (or upvote) unless you provide more descriptions in your answer. As it stands, it seems to be mostly link-only...

Comment: It might help if you explain why you ask this question in the first place. Your question is very terse, so is my reply... Did you find the second form somewhere?

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to edit in some details for people who come a-knockin'. And yes, I did...

Comment: As a full sentence or just a part of?

Comment: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/sza_924782 - The french-translated page of this includes that...

Comment: Translated by what/who? In any case, the translation should be *Mes parents voulaient que j'aille à l'école*. The last part doesn't make a sentence, just a part of it.